# Connect to SQL Compact 4.0 with ADO connection

Tags: sql-server-ce, oledb, compact-database

Using the SQL Compact version 4.0 from [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/de-de/details.aspx?FamilyID=033cfb76-5382-44fb-bc7e-b3c8174832e2), I've created a new compact database on `E:\tmp\EmbSQL.sdf` with SQL Studio.

Trying to connect from Excel Macro:

```
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
strCnxn = "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\tmp\EmbSQL.sdf;"   
conn.Open strCnxn
```

Getting the following error:

> 'Runtime Error -2147467259 (80004005)'.

Any hint on what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates a access denied situation. Is the E: drive a local drive? and do you have write accessto the folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the database to 4.0, SqlceEngine.Upgrade.